# JSON response from PHP is taking too long to return to Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, amazon-ec2, wamp

**Overview:**

I am developing a image based website which is expected to load within 1 sec, there are about 1800 images in the repository as of now and its growing. Currently I load all the product details in the initial ajax call, store them in a client side array and render first 20 images on the UI and subsequently load other images on scroll. It takes around 9-10sec for the site to load and 7-8 secs for the response to come from the server.

**Things I have tried:**

I tried checking the MYSQL response time and it is also very negligible. I was unsure of why it is taking so long to return the response, so I created a mock up method to return the same set of records by parsing the file instead of querying from the database but still it takes 6-7 secs for the server to return the records.

Can someone suggest why the response takes so long for relatively less records and advice what can be done to improve the performance?

**Environment:**

PHP,MYSQL,WAMP hosted on AWS EC2 free tier.

[image]

Comment: I believe Instead of fetch all records in once, Fetch records when user scroll down or on the event of pagination in data-table so records fetching faster...

Comment: @ManojPatel Thanks, I did that because it will be a smooth experience for the user if all the data is preloaded, user doesn't have to wait until next set of records are fetched when scrolling. Also it will reduce server hits.

Comment: Have you eliminated possible issues with your network or wifi? What gap in timestamps do you see in the server-side logs?

Comment: Have you considered a cache like redis to avoid querying mysql?

Comment: @JohnWu You were right the slowness was due to my broadband limitations, I checked everything and forgot to check that. Thanks :)

Comment: @Conti Thanks for your response Conti, the issue was due to broadband limitations. how ever can you please navigate to a place where I can learn more about redis to avoid querying?

Comment: @GokulanPH Think of Redis as an intermediate agent that runs in memory where you can put items (with or without expire time) to avoid reaching the whole backend of the app,for example: avoid querying multiple times when only one is necessary. I am using this https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis in my apps.

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic as the apparent solution was not related to programming.